# problemas con el ciclo switch

Tags: c++

Necesito entregar un trabajo mañana y tengo un error en mi código. Creo que el problema está en el `switch`

Se me pide que el programa simule la taquilla de un museo que será inaugurado próximamente. Se estará repitiendo un ciclo para solicitar la edad del visitante y calcular el monto a pagar de acuerdo a la siguiente tabla:

Menores a 6 años --> $10

De 6 a 12 años --> $25

De 12 a 18 años --> $30

De 18 a 65 años --> $65

Mayores de 65 años --> $15

Lo estoy haciendo con ciclo `switch` pero lo estuve haciendo basándome en un trabajo anterior por que era parecido pero no se por que ahora no me esta funcionando.

y me pide el total de visitantes y el total de dinero obtenido.

**EL CODIGO**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*
*A para menores de 6, AA para de 6 a 12, B para de 12 a 18, B65 para los de 65 años y C es para los mayores de edad.
*/
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char categoria;
    cout << "favor de elegir su boleto (A|AA|B|B65|C) : ";
    cin>>categoria;
    switch(categoria){
       Case A: cat1++;
        Total+=10;
       Case B: cat2++;
        Total+=25;
       Case C: cat3++;
        Total+=30;
       Case D: cat4++;
        Total+=65;
       Case E: cat5++;
       Total+=15;
 {
 Cout << "¿quieres comprar otro boleto? (S/N) : ";
 Cin >> boleto;
       If (boleto == 'N') {
         Cout << "gracias por su compra!\n" ;
} else{
      Cout << "OK volveremos a la sección de boletos\n" ;
}
      system ("PAUSE") ;
      resturn EXIT_SUCCESS;
}}
```

[image: el codigo completo]

}}[image: me salen este error y no entiendo por que no se como corregirlo]

Comment: ya coloque el codigo

Comment: perdón es que me base en otro código que tenia, tengo poca experiencia

Comment: acabo de editar el código

Comment: Por favor, edita el código y pon **uno que compile**. Puedo comprender que algunos errores del compilador pueden ser difíciles de entender... pero no es el caso. C++ es **sensible al uso de mayúsculas y minúsculas**, ahí te dejo una pista.

Comment: @Ponces245 he revisado la edición y no veo que hayas editado el código… has editado el texto alrededor del código.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes **MUCHOS** errores en tu código. Y son errores de ni siquiera pasarse a mirar qué está sucediendo, como llaves abiertas `{`cuando deberían estar cerradas, palabras clave en mayúsculas (`Cin`en vez de `cin`), uso de variables (`total`, `boleto`) que ni siquiera están declaradas... Intenta revisar tu código antes de hacer una pregunta.

Ahora, problemas mayores de `C++`:

1. Estas declarando tus variables como `char`s, pero en algunos casos, como `AB`, eso no es un solo carácter, así que partiendo de la base de que tu código estuviera bien, estarías repitiendo casos de uso si usas `A`y `AB`, por ejemplo, al tratarlo como lo mismo! (Agradecimientos a @Eferion. Lee el comentario de abajo para entender el por qué).
2. El switch se va a ejecutar una vez, así que tendrías que ponerlo en un bucle.

Entonces lo que vamos a hacer es poner el `switch` en un bucle hasta que no queramos comprar más boletos con un `bool`, aunque lo puedas hacer como quieras realmente.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*
*A para menores de 6, AA para de 6 a 12, B para de 12 a 18, B65 para los de 65 años y C es para los mayores de edad.
*/
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int categoria;
    int cat1=0, cat2=0, cat3=0, cat4=0, cat5=0, Total=0;
    bool continuar=true;
    while(continuar){
    cout << "favor de elegir su boleto (A|AA|B|B65|C) : ";
    cin>>categoria;
    cout<<endl;
    switch(categoria){
       case 1:  
       cat1++;
        Total+=10;
        break;
       case 2: cat2++;
        Total+=25;
        break;
       case 3: cat3++;
        Total+=30;
        break;
       case 4: cat4++;
        Total+=65;
        break;
       case 5: cat5++;
       Total+=15;
       break;
       case 6: 
       cout<<"adios!"<<endl;
       continuar=false;
    }
    }
    cout<< Total;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4+cat5;
return 0;
}
```

Consejos de nomenclatura en C++: Variables **SIEMPRE** empiezan por minuscula. Si quieres alargar el nombre, como `nombre="roberto";`, para seguir una buena nomenclatura en `c++`, deberías seguirlo con mayusculas: `nombrePersona="roberto";`, y así sucesivamente, `nombrePersonaInteresada="roberto";`

Comment: No está usando `string` en el `switch` sino `char`. De hecho `categoria` es de tipo `char` ... otra cosa es que luego no sea capaz de guardar en esa variable `AA`... Sobre los criterios de nomenclatura no hay consenso, así que del último párrafo sobra la mitad.

Comment: De hecho no está usando ni `char`, está usando ¿"`Case`"? (la ce mayúscula) sobre literales que no representan ningún símbolo… (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`).

Comment: Qué significa "AA" es una string, no un carácter, aunque definido como carácter y sin reservar memoria, es cierto que se quedaría como dices @eferion

Lo que he estudiado en la carrera a nivel internacional es que se suele usar camelCase nivel genérico y se recomienda siempre hacerlo así, igual que en python se usa `este_tipo_de_estilo`. Consensuado como tal no estará, quizá. Sigo sin ver el motivo por el cual votar hacia abajo esta respuesta.

Comment: Si tu escribes `AA` y el programa lo guarda en un `char`, solo se recupera el primer caracter... el segundo se queda en el buffer hasta la siguiente lectura... En cuanto al nombrado... la triste realidad es que el nombrado es libre. Así puedes tener `una_variable` o `unavariable` o `unaVariable`.

Comment: Edito la respuesta con respecto a este apunte, gracias! @eferion

Comment: El voto negativo viene por los errores que contiene la respuesta. Eso sin contar con el hecho de que la pregunta, tal y como está redactada, no debería obtener respuesta aunque fuese simplemente por amor propio. Este servicio es gratuito, por lo que exigir un mínimo a la hora de redactar las preguntas debería ser una especie de obligación implícita

Comment: Entiendo.. No comparto lo que dices en ciertos puntos pero entiendo el por qué. Gracias por el feedback. Mejoraré mis futuras respuestas en SO @eferion

Comment: Se puede ver con otra perspectiva... ¿Tu verías con buenos ojos que alguien te pidiese hacer un programa de forma gratuita alegando que eso supone una oportunidad para ti porque te va a dar más visibilidad y bla bla bla? Yo personalmente no. Primero porque al hacer ese programa, el usuario va a obtener un beneficio, luego lo justo sería que tu obtuvieses un beneficio también y segundo porque eso de la visibilidad y la publicidad es algo subjetivo y relativo... si tu no valoras tu trabajo no esperes que los demás lo hagan por ti

Comment: En eso tienes razón, de ahí a que las primeras frases de mi respuesta sean con ese tono de "ni siquiera te has esforzado en mirar qué estabas haciendo mal. " Y es algo que en parte me molesta. Quiero decir, parece que ni se ha leído el log de los errores que le daban... Y a pesar de que es cierto que resolver este problema me ha llevado nada y menos, sigue siendo un trabajo y como tal, fácil o difícil, la otra persona obtiene un beneficio... Entonces por qué no "flaggearla" para cerrarla? @eferion por mala calidad, etc.?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100246/discussion-between-eferion-and-m-k).